# restTemplate.put when updating the data that contains a list gives "Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT"

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

My code snippet is given below.

```
    ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList();
    list.add("test");
    Map<String, List> params = new HashMap<String, List>();
    params.put("1", list1);     
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();        
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);       
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(params,headers );
    restTemplate.put(uri, entity);
```

Getting the response as "Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token\".
Does anyone face this similar issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40079053/spring-resttemplate-send-list-an-get-list

Answer (score 2):

You can convert `Map` to `Json` String and then pass to entity,

```
String paramsString = new Gson().toJson(params);
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(paramsString,headers);
restTemplate.put(uri, entity);
```